# Google Chrome Browser Sync using Google Apps Domain

Tags: google-chrome, synchronization, single-sign-on, google-apps

I have a bit of a nagging problem here. At my current position, we have a Google Apps domain set up (for the sake of this question, it will be pennmanor.net) and I would like to determine a way to log in to Google Chrome (the web browser) and connect the Apps account to sync the settings.

I have found this article: [Bug Report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19589#c64) that describes the issue, which has been resolved. I have made sure that the options described in Comment 64 are correct, but still no sync. Other articles suggest that it is simply a matter of punching in the credentials and thats it.

We do have a custom SSO and Active Directory set up with the apps account, would this possibly be the cause of the problem?

Does anyone know what I might need to do to enable account Google Chrome to sync pennmanor.net account?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting user's Google password? Chrome Sync will not use the SSO password. If your users are stored in Active Directory, you can use the Google Apps Password Sync tool to sync passwords from AD to Google as they are changed:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2611859